# Can't use string when importing row data from csv to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

as part of an exercise I have to insert one row from a csv per second into my postgres db. Everything works fine as long as none of my rows contain strings. I'm wondering how I can make only my strings have ' ' when adding the variable to my INSERT statement.

```
with open(file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  next(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    print(row)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % (tbl_name, cols, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4],row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15]))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never build a query containing values as a full string(*), but use a parameterized query

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    % (tbl_name, cols), row[:15]))
```

But some engines do not like `?`, in that case, you can use `%s`:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)"
    % (tbl_name, cols), row[:15]))
```

---

This pattern is deprecated for ages because it was the cause of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks...

Comment: Thanks I tried but got syntax error at the first comma after ?.

Comment: Thanks! That syntax works if all the values in the row are integers, but now I have the same problem, where if an entry is a string, it brings it into the INSERT statement as a string without quotations. the cols variable is passing the appropriate data type (string if the entry is a string, int if it's an int) at table creation so that isn't the issue.

Comment: Nvm it works just had to change [:15] to [:16] thanks for taking the time to look at it!